# Googlebot and other crawlers are clicking on javascript links

Tags: javascript, seo, vue.js

We are running Vue.js on one of our applications, and are generating anchor tags with it. Google is crawling this, as we can see from search results. However, it is also crawling with a bot that has JavaScript disabled, and encounters links like the following:

`<a href="/electronica/{{ auction.main_image_big }}"></a>`

This is generating errors in our Laravel application, because they come into our webserver as:

`/electronica/%7B%7B%20auction.main_image_big%20%7D%7D`

What is the best approach to prevent a crawler without JavaScript enabled to click on these links. Redirect them to another page?

Keep in mind that we still want Googlebot to crawl these links when JavaScript is enabled, because these links lead to all of our products.

Answer (score 2):

use v-bind instead:

```
<a v-bind:href="'/electronica/' + auction.main_image_big"></a>
```

or with v-bind short version and ES6 string templates:

```
<a :href="`/electronica/${auction.main_image_big}`"></a>
```

As this won't be turned into a `href` attribute without Javascript enabled, the bot will skip those.

It's also future-proof with regards to Vue 2.0, as interpolations in attributes are being removed.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your reply. I have implemented this solution, and will let you know if it works